# Behaviour of tap for recursive functions

Tags: ruby, recursion, combinators

I like to use tap occasionally as a beautifier for method returns.  However, when using tap with a recursive function, it's behavior is different than what I expect:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :name, :children

  def initialize(name); self.name, self.children = name, []; end

  def render
    res = "Name: #{name}\n"
    children.each do |child|
      res += " - " + child.render + "\n"
    end
    res
  end
end

parent = Node.new('Parent')
parent.children = [Node.new('Child')]
puts parent.render
```

Returns

```
Name: Parent
 - Name: Child
```

If I change the render function to use tap:

```
  def render
    "Name: #{name}\n".tap do |res|
      children.each do |child|
        res += " - " + child.render + "\n"
      end
    end
  end
```

It returns

```
Name: Parent
```

I would assume the behavior would be identical to the first render function.  The docs indicate it "Yields x to the block, and then returns x"...since the function is recursing is it somehow polluting the function stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with anything except that assignment changes a variable, and variables are passed by value. `tap` is irrelevant, the behavior is identical if you place a string into *any* variable.

In your case, you're passing a string literal into a proc, which receives a variable called `res` containing a copy of that string. You're then modifying that variable, **not** the original string itself.

Consider:

```
def test(res)
  res += "bar"
end

x = "foo"
test(x)
puts x # outputs "foo", not "foobar"
```

The reason your first example works is that you're **replacing** the value in the string `res` with a new value. You're not actually appending data to the string stored in `res`.

Comment: `String`s in Ruby are very much mutable. There are a ton of mutation methods on `String`: `<<`, `[]=`, `clear`, `concat`, `prepend`, `setbyte`, `force_encoding`, `insert`, `replace`, `sub!`, `gsub!`, `capitalize!`, `chomp!`, `chop!`, `delete!`, `downcase!`, `upcase!`, `encode!`, `lstrip!`, `strip!`, `next!`, `succ!`, `reverse!`, `scrub!`, `rstrip!`, `slice!`, `squeeze!`, `swapcase!`, `tr!`, `tr_s!`.

Comment: Strings are not immutable, however anytime you use an assignment operator, you're actually altering which object to which the left side of the `=` refers rather than changing the value of that object.